# Understanding Memory Allocation Behavior with JSON Unmarshal in Go

Tags: json, go, memory

I'm investigating the memory allocation behavior in Go, particularly when unmarshalling JSON data into structs. My observation revolves around two different approaches to unmarshalling and how they seem to affect memory usage and garbage collection.

The first approach (A()) involves unmarshalling JSON directly into an array of structs, while the second approach (B()) unmarshals the JSON into a temporary variable before assigning it to the array. Surprisingly, these similar-looking approaches yield significantly different memory usage results, which I'm trying to understand.

Here's a simplified version of the code I'm working with:

```golang
package main

import (
    "encoding/json"
    "fmt"
    "runtime"
    "strings"
)

const (
    iter     = 100000
    buffsize = 100000
    datalen  = 5000
)

type Object struct {
    Data string
}

func A() {
    b, _ := json.Marshal(Object{Data: strings.Repeat("A", datalen)})

    var buf [buffsize]Object
    for i := range iter {
        _ = json.Unmarshal(b, &buf[i])
    }

    printMemUsage()
}

func B() {
    b, _ := json.Marshal(Object{Data: strings.Repeat("B", datalen)})

    var buf [buffsize]Object
    var t Object
    for i := range iter {
        _ = json.Unmarshal(b, &t)
        buf[i] = t
    }

    printMemUsage()
}

func main() {
    A()
    runtime.GC()
    B()
}

func printMemUsage() {
    var m runtime.MemStats
    runtime.ReadMemStats(&m)
    fmt.Printf("Alloc = %v MiB", m.Alloc/1024/1024)
    fmt.Printf("\tTotalAlloc = %v MiB", m.TotalAlloc/1024/1024)
    fmt.Printf("\tSys = %v MiB", m.Sys/1024/1024)
    fmt.Printf("\tNumGC = %v\n", m.NumGC)
}
```

The output indicates a significant difference in memory allocation between the two functions:

```
Alloc = 521 MiB TotalAlloc = 535 MiB    Sys = 543 MiB   NumGC = 8
Alloc = 2 MiB   TotalAlloc = 1068 MiB   Sys = 543 MiB   NumGC = 158
```

I'm trying to understand why function A() seems to hold onto memory, preventing the garbage collector from reclaiming it, while B() does not exhibit this behavior, even though their operations appear similar. Does this have to do with how references are handled during unmarshalling in Go?

Any insights or explanations would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Contrived benchmarks like this are often misleading. You're not doing anything with the results, and `buf` doesn't escape to the heap in `B`, so there's no allocation.

Comment: Also note that `TotalAlloc` has gone up a comparable amount, if you turn off GC then you will probably still see those allocations.

Comment: Your "benchmark" attempt produces erroneous results and leads you to erroneous conclusions. In fact, the memory usage (bytes and allocations) of A() and B() are the same. Use the Go testing package for benchmarks.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification! I've verified that the total number of allocations and the overall memory consumption are identical for functions `A` and `B`. By forcing both buffers onto the heap, I observed consistent memory usage between the two.

However, I'm left with one lingering question: How can I cap memory usage to ensure that invoking GC effectively frees up memory? Currently, setting an environment variable like `GOMEMLIMIT` or using `debug.SetMemoryLimit()` results in more frequent GC cycles, but it doesn't seem to release the allocated memory as expected.

Comment: A garbage collector does not free memory, it reuses it. Memory needs to remain unused for a sufficiently long time to be released back to the OS. Read also https://tip.golang.org/doc/gc-guide